# Huge empty space

Tags: spacing

I'm a beginner at using LaTeX and I keep getting weird behaviours. For example, on the image below, I get so much empty space. Why is that ? How can I remove it ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/31058)! Could you edit your question in order to add a MWE for us to help you?

Comment: How should I edit it ?

Comment: You have the edit "button" at the very bottom of your question next to "share" and "flag". You should add to your question the code you used to produce the output on your picture (or at least a part of this code which is compilable and reproduce the problem you want to get help with).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please in future post code that we can copy (preferably a complete document) rather than a screenshot of code, however..

You are using `\FloatBarrier` so the float can not float further forward past the next section title, the image is clipped but I suspect that you already have top floats on that page up to the number allowed by your document class so the float can not go at the top. By default `h` floats are not allowed, which leaves `b` bottom float as the only possibility to be tried before `p` which would cause an extra page to be issued with just the float.

probably in this case using `\begin{figure}[!htp]` will make things look better

`!` says to ignore numeric constraints (so it will probably go in the top area)

`htp` allow *here*, *top* and *page* floats and disallow `b` *bottom*.